# How to automatically set good camera position in R3F

Tags: next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm building a model viewer and apparently whenever I load a 3D model (type: GLB), the camera position is just messed up. I have seen other online 3d model viewers and all of them somehow manage to get a good camera angle regardless of the model I'm loading.
Is there any possible way to achieve this?

This is my code to render a model of a chair

```js
const gltf = useGLTF("chair.glb")

/*
Other code here
*/

<Canvas>
    <OrbitControls />
    <Environment preset="sunset" blur={0.8} />
    <primitive object={gltf.scene} scale={scale} />
</Canvas>
```

This is how the chair is being rendered. It is way above origin for some reason.
[Image of Chair Model rendered using R3F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytnfp.png)

Comment: This might be more a question for https://photo.stackexchange.com/, since picking a correct camera position is the most difficult part of photography   (But then they have no clue about programming....)

Comment: I would seek to see for the BoundingBox of the object first and place my camera at a distance relative to the bounding box first. Then I would seek to find a magnitude value based on the size of the BB to always have a camera at a same magnitude if it makes sense.

Comment: @Axiome could you mention a ref of BoundingBox usage for this case? or any example code snippet is appreciated too! Thank you in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Center } from '@react-three/drei';

export default function App() {

const gltf = useGLTF("chair.glb")

/*
Other code here
*/

<Canvas>
    <OrbitControls />
    <Environment preset="sunset" blur={0.8} />
   <Center>
    <primitive object={gltf.scene} scale={scale} />
   </Center>
</Canvas>
}
```

Have you tried this?